# proton wira 2004 user and repair manuals

Tags: manual-transmission, repair, colt

My car which is a proton wira 2004 is acting up and I have been played a fool by many mechanics and technicians.
So I would greatly appreciate if someone could point to the user and repair manuals of the proton wira 2004 which is I believe in essence mitsubishi colt 1994.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search for manuals for mitsubishi colt 1994 gives :
as one result - I am not posting the files themselves and they run to several hundred pages but a simple search gives plenty of what you need...
[image: manual links]